# Passing a selected row from a GSP's table to a Controller in Grails 3.0

Tags: grails, controller, gsp

I have one controller that sends a list of users data (UserID, FirstName, LastName, email) to a GSP.
The GSP displays the data into a table of 5 columns where the 5th column is a submit button so one particular row in the table can be selected. That selected row of data is then passed back to the same controller for further processing.
I am new to Grails 3 and have not found a similar use case. 
It seems to me that Grails does not have an equivalent of the JSF dataTable. I need pointers on how to do this without using JavaScript or JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grails [http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html](http://remoteFunction) which can be assigned to Dom event to call the remote method. For example If you have a regular button you can add the following code:

```
onclick="<g:remoteFunction action='modify' id='${user.id}'/>"
```

Another option to use would be [http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.7/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html](http://submitToRemote) which creates a button that submits the containing form as a remote Ajax call. Here url parameter can be used as per documentation:

```
url - The url to submit to, either a map contraining keys for the action, controller and id or a string value
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Feras. The remoteFunction, submitToRemote are not in Grails 3.0 unless I am missing something. I got this error " Tag [remoteFunction] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g" and when I look up the documentation the tags are not there.